# Scrapy : restrict_css with bad formatted HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The HTML code I am trying to crawl is bad formatted :

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    My items here...
    My items here...
    My items here...

    Pagination here...
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

The problem is the second `</head>`. I must replace the HTML in my spider to use the xpath expressions :

```
class FooSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'foo'
    allowed_domains = ['foo.bar']
    start_urls = ['http://foo.bar/index.php?page=1']
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\?page=\d',),),
              callback="parse_start_url",
              follow=True),)

def parse_start_url(self, response):
    # Remove the second </head> here
    # Perform my item
```

Now I want to use the `restrict_xpath` argument in my rule, but I can't because the HTML is bad formatted : replacement has not been performed at this time.

Do you have an idea please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is write a [Downloader middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/downloader-middleware.html) and use, for instance, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package to fix and prettify the HTML contained inside `response.body` - [`response.replace()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.replace) might be handy in this case.

Note that, if you would go with `BeautifulSoup`, choose a [parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) carefully - each parser has it's own way into the broken HTML - some are less or more lenient. `lxml.html` would be the best in terms of speed though.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "lxml")
        response = response.replace(body=soup.prettify())

        return response
```

As an example, of a custom middleware that modifies the downloaded HTML, see [`scrapy-splash` middleware](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash/blob/master/scrapyjs/middleware.py).

Comment: Oh, it's perfect ! Thank you :)