# Why does Scrapy Selector fail to parse all the tags?

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

Hi there and thats for looking at my question,

The problem I have is that scrapy selector seems not to parse correctly tags of a site.

```
    pp re.findall("meta.*",response.body)
['meta name="verify-v1" content="C4vnWz0WNdkra4aXTdZ9iegoTDhnazsNf0RVwXaT9eM=">\r',
 'meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />\r',
 'meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.cg_n" content="Part Search" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.cg_s" content="Part Detail" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.ti" content="Part Detail" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.z_page_type" content="PS" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.z_page_sub_type" content="PD" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.z_page_id" content="PD" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.pn_sku" content=481-2&quot;X36YD-ND />\r',
 'meta name="WT.z_part_id" content=1819153 />\r',
 'meta name="WT.tx_e" content="v" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.tx_u" content="1" />\r',
 'meta name="WT.z_supplier_id" content=19 />\r',
 'meta itemprop="productID" content="sku:481-2&quot;X36YD-ND" />\r',
 'meta itemprop="name" content="481-2&quot;X36YD" />\r']
ipdb> pp response.xpath("//meta")
[<Selector xpath='//meta' data=u'<meta name="verify-v1" content="C4vnWz0W'>,
 <Selector xpath='//meta' data=u'<meta http-equiv="content-type" content='>,
 <Selector xpath='//meta' data=u'<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" conte'>,
 <Selector xpath='//meta' data=u'<meta name="description" content=\'Find 3'>]
ipdb>
```

I can't figure out why this is happening and why the other tags don't get parsed even if they exist on site?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share a link to the website so that we can reproduce that too? Thanks.

Comment: example link would be this [link](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/481-2%22X36YD/481-2%22X36YD-ND/1819153). For now I have figured out that the problem is in lxml and not scrapy so the tittle might be misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) with the built-in `html.parser` handles this particular markup better:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/481-2%22X36YD/481-2%22X36YD-ND/1819153
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, "html.parser")
>>>
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([meta["content"] for meta in soup.find_all("meta")])
[u'C4vnWz0WNdkra4aXTdZ9iegoTDhnazsNf0RVwXaT9eM=',
 u'text/html',
 u'IE=edge',
 u'Find 3M 481-2"\x00X36YD (481-2"\x00X36YD-ND) at DigiKey.  Check stock and pricing, view product specifications, and order online.',
 u'481-2"\x00X36YD, 3M, Tape',
 u'Digi-Key Search Engine',
 u'Part Search',
 u'Part Detail',
 u'Part Detail',
 u'PS',
 u'PD',
 u'PD',
 u'481-2"X36YD-ND',
 u'1819153',
 u'v',
 u'1',
 u'19',
 u'sku:481-2"X36YD-ND',
 u'481-2"X36YD']
```

What you can actually do in your Scrapy project is to pass the `response.body` through the `BeautifulSoup` HTML Parser in a middleware - basically "fixing" the broken HTML with `BeautifulSoup`. This would not require any changes to the spider you already have. Here is a sample middleware implementation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32567951/771848

Comment: Thank You, I would probably end up using BeautifulSoup but somehow I can't part from all the nice features of a scrapy Selector class.

Comment: @TomislavRupcic gotcha, updated the answer with an idea to have a "fixing HTML" middleware based on `BeautifulSoup`. What is good about this approach is that you would not need to change the spider at all and can continue using all of the Scrapy features.